# Octave Mapping over Rows

Tags: matrix, mapping, row, octave, vectorization

I have a matrix that's m x 2:

```
.2 .8
.3 .7
.7 .3

...
```

and I would like to map the '>' operation to each row, resulting in the column like so:

```
0
0
1

...
```

However, I can't seem to find a good way to do this without removing columns and applying a custom function to the matrix in something like

```
res = arrayfun(@mapfunction, matrix(:,1))

function cl = mapfunction(v)
    cl = v > .5
```

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply calculate a Boolean / `logical` column that checks to see whether the first column is greater than the second column for every row in your matrix:

```
res = matrix(:,1) > matrix(:,2);
```

---

Given your example matrix:

```
matrix = [.2 .8; .3 .7; .7 .3];
```

This is what I get:

```
>> res = matrix(:,1) > matrix(:,2)

res =

     0
     0
     1
```

Comment: @PhilipMassey - Thanks :) Yeah I answered a bit too early lol.... about a minute and a half after you posted.  Good timing though, and I know I have to wait.  Thanks for voting up though!